# Error running List PROJECTS in microstrategy command manager

Tags: microstrategy

I'm trying to run the script below in microstrategy command manager.  I'm getting the error code below.  Does anyone know what the issue might be and what I need to do to solve it?

```
Code:

LIST PROJECTS;


Error:

Syntax is correct.
(You do not have Monitor Cluster privilege that is required to perform the task.)
Task(s) execution completed with errors.
Execution Time: 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of privileges granted directly to the user or group and not granted from a security role.

This particular privilege is one of those. Edit your user or one of the groups to which your user belongs and click “Project Access”. Scroll down to the “Administration” group and check “Monitor cluster”.

You can see more of these privileges [in the Admin Supplemental guide.](https://www2.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.6/SupplementalAdmin/WebHelp/Lang_1033/Content/AdminSupplemental/Administration_privileges.htm#privileges_3197779064_1011337) Those that are “server level” are granted directly to the user or group and not from a security role.